# How to delete an element from a abstract class

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, abstract-class, destructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

//

class Persoana {
public:
    int varsta;
    string nume, prenume;
    //constructor vid cu scopu pentru declararea vectorului
    Persoana() {}
    Persoana(string nume, string prenume, int age)
    {
        this->nume = nume;
        this->prenume = prenume;
        varsta = age;
    }
    virtual void afisare()
    {
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Numele: " << nume << "\n";
        cout << "Prenumele: " << prenume << "\n";
        cout << "Varsta: " << Persoana::varsta << "\n";
    }
    string returnName()
    {
        return nume;
    }

    ~Persoana() {};

};

class Angajat :public Persoana {
public:
    string departament;
    int salariu;
    Angajat() {}
    Angajat(string nume, string prenume, int varsta, string departament, int salariu)
        :Persoana(nume, prenume, varsta)
    {
        this->departament = departament;
        this->salariu = salariu;
    }
    virtual void afisare()
    {
        Persoana::afisare();
        cout << "Departament: " << departament << endl;
        cout << "Salariu: " << salariu << endl;
    }
    //Mai jos este sunt 3 "gathers" , care returneaza nume, prenume, varsta
    string returnNume() {
        return nume;
    }

    string returnPrenume() {
        return prenume;
    }

    int returnVarsta()
    {
        return varsta;
    }

};

class Student : public Persoana {
public:
    string tip;
    int an;
    Student() {}
    Student(string nume, string prenume, int varsta, string tip, int an)
        :Persoana(nume, prenume, varsta)
    {
        this->tip = tip;
        this->an = an;
    }

    string returnNume()
    {
        return nume;
    }

    string returnPrenume()
    {
        return prenume;
    }
    int returnAge()
    {
        return varsta;
    }

    virtual void afisare() {
        Persoana::afisare();
        cout << "Tip:" << tip << endl;
        cout << "Varsta:" << varsta << endl;
    }
    
};

void menu()
{
    string n, p, d;
    int i_2=0,v, s, i=0, ok = 0, ok2 = 0, nr=0 , opt, nr2 = 0,nr3=0;
    string num, num2;
    Student student[40];
    Angajat angajat[40];
    Persoana * persoane[80];
    int choice;
    do
    {
        cout << "0.Adaugare student" << endl;
        cout << "1.Adaugare angajat" << endl;
        cout << "2. Cautare" << endl;
        cout << "3. Stergere" << endl;
        cout << "4. Exit" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 0:
            
            nr++;
            cout << "Dati numele: ";
            cin >> n;
            cout << "Dati prenumele: ";
            cin >> p;
            cout << "Dati varsta: ";
            cin >> v;
            cout << "Dati tip: ";
            cin >> d;
            cout << "Dati an:";
            cin >> s;   
            student[nr2] = Student(n, p, v, d, s);
            persoane[i] = &student[nr2];
            nr2 = nr2 + 1;
            i = i + 1;
                for (i = 0; i < nr; i++)
                {
                    persoane[i]->afisare();
                }
            break;
        case 1:
            
            //retin numaru de studenti si angajati(in total) prin acest nr
            nr++;
            cout << "Dati numele: ";
            cin >> n;
            cout << "Dati prenumele: ";
            cin >> p;
            cout << "Dati varsta: ";
            cin >> v;
            cout << "Dati departamentul: ";
            cin >> d;
            cout << "Dati salariul:";
            cin >> s;
            
            angajat[nr3] = Angajat(n, p, v, d, s);
            persoane[i] = &angajat[nr3];
            nr3++;
            i++;
            break;
        case 2:
                       //this search is working perfectly fine :)
            cout << "Introduceti numele persoanei: ";
            cin >> num;
            ok = 0;
            
            
            for (i = 0; i < nr; i++)
            {
                
                if ((num.compare(persoane[i]->returnName())) == 0)
                {
                    persoane[i]->afisare();
                }
                ok++;
            }
            if (ok == 0)
                cout << "Aceasta persoana nu se afla in institutie:(";
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Introduceti numele pe care vreti sa il ste/rgeti:";
            cin >> num2;
            //here i want to delete an element, but when this is running will delete everything from my class:(
            for (i = 0; i < nr; i++)
            {
                if (num2.compare(persoane[i]->returnName()) == 0)
                {
                    persoane[i]->~Persoana(); 
                    nr--;
                    ok2++;
                }
            }
            if (ok2 == 0)
            {
                cout << "Element not found";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Elementul a fost sters:";
            }
            break;
        case 4:         
            exit(0);
        }
    } while (choice != 4);
}


int main()
{
    menu();
}
```

In this program i create 2 child class from class Persoana, class Student and class Angajat ,in the menu at option 3 , it will ask you for a name to delete , my problem is that the function i created is deleting the whole class Persoana, i really dont know how to use destructors and abstract classes

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by `deleting the whole class Persoana`? When deleting, an object cannot (and should not) be deleted partially, it's all or nothing step.

Comment: Terminology problem. Can you give an example of what you mean by element?

Comment: I also don't see any [abstract classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class), so you might what to explain what you mean there as well.

Comment: `persoane[i]->~Persoana();` isn't right, what are you trying to achieve by doing that?  Also (and this might bite you later), `Persoana`'s destructor should be `virtual`.

Comment: You are right ,the destructor should be virtual,ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are instantiating `Student`s and `Angajat`s statically. You will not be able to `delete` them.

```cpp
    Student student[40]; // static allocation of 40 students
    Angajat angajat[40]; // static allocation of 40 angajats
    Persoana * persoane[80]; // static allocation of 80 pointers to students and angajats base classes.
```

- First of all, you *need* to declare the `Persoana` destructor as `virtual`, to invoke derived classes destructors: `virtual ~Persoana(){/*whatever*/}`
- Instantiate the `Student`s and `Angajat`s dynamically. I.e: To create a new instance of `Student`s you should use :

  ```
  Persoana* student = new Student();
  ```

And consider using the STL *list* : `std::list<Persoana*>`, `::push_back(..)`, and its *iterators* to search and delete elements.

> that example creates a list of *pointers* to `Persoana`. Deleting the item of the list will NOT delete the item. For that, you have to use the `delete` operator.

Comment: Most direct map to an array is `std::vector` rather than `std::list` `std::list` is typically implemented as a doubly linked list and benefits from quick insert and removal, but those benefits are usually obliterated by how poorly they perform when walking through the list to find where the item needs to be inserted or removed.